# Entity Framework - Include 4th (fourth) level and beyond

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible in EF to include 4th level and maybe even deeper?

What i've tried:

```
var anime = AnimeTimeDbContext.Animes
                        .Include(a => a.Images.Select(ai => ai.Image.Thumbnails))
```

And:

```
var anime = AnimeTimeDbContext.Animes
                        .Include(a => a.Images.Select(ai => ai.Image).Select(i => i.Thumbnails))
```

But without success.

I know that in EF Core we can use .ThenInclude, but i can't switch atm.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The code doesn't work as in it doesn't return the Thumbnails, it just returns empty Collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF6 supports including multiple levels, it's just a bit more clumsy than EF Core. Give this a try:

```
var anime = AnimeTimeDbContext.Animes
    .Include(a => a.Images)
    .Include(a => a.Images.Select(i => i.Thumbnails));
```

The first Include includes the Images, the second tells EF to include the Thumbnails for each image.

Comment: It works. Including Images first did the trick. Thank you!